# Retina MacBook Pro freezes after replacement screen fitted

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

I have a rMBP 975, mid-2012, running 10.9.1, and half a month ago, I went to the Genius bar to change my screen. After that, in the past week, my Mac has frozen  three times. I don't know what the problem is, but I guess it might be because they didn't install the screen well.

Here is the crash log:

```
Dec 27 14:32:00 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [67492346370432]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
Dec 27 14:32:00 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
Dec 27 14:32:01 paradox-3.local SCIM[12117]: librarian connection is invalid: Connection invalid
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local SecurityAgent[11426]: User info context values set for jeswang
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: Auditing enabled
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: Got low space trigger
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: auditd_read_dirs(): all audit log directories over soft limit
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local _securityagent[15484]: audit warning: allsoft 
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local _securityagent[15485]: audit warning: soft /var/audit
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: renamed /var/audit/20131227042039.not_terminated to /var/audit/20131227042039.20131227063204
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: New audit file is /var/audit/20131227063204.not_terminated
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local _securityagent[15488]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20131227042039.20131227063204
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local SCIM[12117]: librarian connection is invalid: Connection invalid
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local SecurityAgent[11426]: Login Window login proceeding
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local loginwindow[11381]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Session 256 is switching to console
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Session 258 released (1 references)
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Session 258 released (0 references)
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local loginwindow[11381]: CGError CGSGetDisplaySystemState(uint64_t, CGSDisplaySystemState **): MIG error 0xfffffecc: (ipc/mig) server died
Dec 27 14:32:05 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local loginwindow[11381]: _backingStore failed - error -308 (backingStore:2595)
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: run_timer_pass: Session 258 is defunct for callback to 0x7fff8cde12d1
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: run_timer_pass: Session 258 is defunct for callback to 0x7fff8cc30d9a
Dec 27 14:32:05 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
... same words ...
Dec 27 14:32:06 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:06 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:07 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: run_timer_pass: Session 0 is defunct for callback to 0x7fff8cc2ff67
Dec 27 14:32:07 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 27 14:32:07 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Dec 27 14:32:07 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Display 0x042803c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Dec 27 14:32:11 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15497]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:32:11 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15497]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:32:11 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15497]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:32:11 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15497]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:32:12 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15498]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:32:13 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15498]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:32:13 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15498]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:32:13 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15498]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:32:14 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:32:14 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:32:14 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:32:14 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:32:15 paradox-3.local locationd[64]: wifi scan failed with error: @
Dec 27 14:32:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 27 14:32:15 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
Dec 27 14:32:19 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42803c0
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 62 modes for display 0x042803c0 [36, 26]
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042803c0 device: 0x7fed2a900e20  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42803c0
Dec 27 14:32:19 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x042803c0 [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:20 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15501]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:32:25 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15499]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
Dec 27 14:32:30 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42803c0
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 29 modes for display 0x042803c0 [18, 11]
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42803c0
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x042803c0 [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local Dictionary[6792]: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Dec 27 14:32:30 paradox-3.local WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042803c0 device: 0x7fed2a900e20  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Dec 27 14:32:54 paradox-3 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::getKEY_RSC: Requesting RSC for index 2.
Dec 27 14:32:54 paradox-3 kernel[0]: wlc_ioctl(WLC_GET_KEY_SEQ) returned 0
Dec 27 14:33:19 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15509]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:33:19 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15509]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:33:19 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15509]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:33:19 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15509]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:33:36 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15510]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:33:36 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15510]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:33:36 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15510]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:33:36 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15510]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:33:37 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15511]: Internals of CFAllocator not known; out-of-memory failures via CFAllocator will not result in termination. http://crbug.com/45650
Dec 27 14:33:37 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15511]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
Dec 27 14:33:37 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15511]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
Dec 27 14:33:37 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15511]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
Dec 27 14:33:37 paradox-3.local Google Chrome Helper[15510]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFECC) from font server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the free space on the HD. These warnings in the log point are the key:

```
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: Got low space trigger
Dec 27 14:32:04 paradox-3.local auditd[15480]: auditd_read_dirs(): all audit log directories over soft limit
```

Comment: You maybe right, I experienced several time WindowServer down and this warning always appear.